# Android Studio emulator work but app is not running

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I run my application on android studio. Emulator work but app is not run. I try rebuild, debugging, invalidate and restart, close and open android studio a few times, cold boot emulator, wipe data and none of them work. What should I do?

Comment: What does the Build log say when you try to run it? (bottom tab in Android Studio you might need to expand). Or is the app crashing?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you. It must be the new update, only thing I do different is I update Android Studio. I didn't see there's a new update.